# Opera don't fire onLoad everytime - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I have a problem with JavaScript and Opera. 
I want to fire an JavaScript function onLoad but opera
ignores it when I reload the page or use the back button to come back.

My code looks like this:

```
  HTML 
  ...
 <body onload = "doSomething()">
  ...


    //Javascript
    if (window.opera)  
{  
    opera.setOverrideHistoryNavigationMode('compatible');  
    history.navigationMode = 'compatible';  
} 
...
    function doSomething(){
         alert("HI");
    }
```

The first time I load the page I get an Alert but if 
I reload the page or use the back button to come back I 
don't get an alert.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? 
Chrome, Firefox and even IE work fine.

Comment: What is your Opera version? I use Opera 36.0 on Mac and cannot reproduce the bug. Also, in my environment, `window.opera` is `undefined`.

Comment: I am using Opera 43.0 and I am on Windows.